# object c - release an object which is owner from 2 other objects

Tags: objective-c

from researching memory management on objective C, I have a question about reference count:

I have an object name obj_number. I have alloc it

```
    obj_number = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
```

and then in another method (named A)of this class, I set

```
    obj_number = [dataset objectAtIndex:0];
```

go out this method A dataset will be autorelease. I checked this after go out this method obj_number also can't be access, maybe it also be deallocate.

I see if an object just be under one ownership, so if parent deallocate it also be deallocate, but in my case I suppose that obj_number under 2 ownership (retain count may equals to 2), so why running out method A it be released?

Comment: no, if using ARC, I can't understand memory management of objective c, I think it's not good for my studying

Comment: You realize that `[[NSNumber alloc] init]` returns nil for fairly obvious reasons?

Comment: Thanks for all answer, all of them are useful for my problem. If stackoverflow allow me to accept all of this, I would appreciate to do this. ;) @trojanfoe has figure out a solution and I success with trying it, it make me more clearly. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a setter method for `obj_number`, which you can do by providing a `@property` in the `.h` file and a `@sythesize` in the `.m` file.  The setter method will ensure that the old value is released and the new value is retained.

MyClass.h:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSNumber *_obj_number;    // Use a different name for the ivar and property!
    ...
}

@property (retain, nonatomic, readwrite) NSNumber *obj_number;

...

@end
```

MyClass.m:

```
@implementation MyObject
@synthesize obj_number = _obj_number;

...

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.obj_number = nil;
    ...
    [super dealloc];
}
```

And when assigning to `obj_number`, you must relinquish ownership:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    // We own myNumber, so release
    NSNumber *myNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsigned:12];
    self.obj_number = myNumber;
    [myNumber release];

    // However this is easier:
    self.obj_number = [NSNumber numberWithUnsigned:12];
}

- (void)someOtherMethod
{
    // We don't own [dataset objectAtIndex:0] so no need to release
    self.obj_number = [dataset objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: so after the line self.obj_number = [dataset objectAtIndex:0]; the property obj_number not be release, right? I see in the setter method, the argument is retained, meant that [dataset objectAtIndex:0] is retained. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Are you using non-ARC ?

In method, you might have like this:

```
-(void)A{
    ....
    obj_number = [dataset objectAtIndex:0];
    [dataset autorelease];
}
```

In the above you are changing the pointer of obj_number to point to `[dataset objectAtIndex:0]`.

As per your `under 2 ownership (retain count may equals to 2)`

I hope your intension would be to `copy` or `retain` this value, right?

Then you can use `obj_number = [[dataset objectAtIndex:0] copy];//or retain` only then its retain count will increase to 2.

Comment: Ah yes, I got it. Maybe I misunderstand somethings around here. thanks so much. :D

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't think in retain count. The important thing is the ownership.

```
obj_number = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
```

Creates a new NSNumber instance that you own. This means that you have to release it when it is not longer needed.

```
obj_number = [dataset objectAtIndex:0];
```

This gives you an object that you don't own. You you don't have to release it. If you want the ownership you must send it a retain message and must release it later.

Another point for your code. If you write something like that you have a memory leak (if you don't use ARC):

```
//obj_number = [[NSNumber alloc] init]; // returns nil, so no leak
obj_number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
some code // No [obj_number release] or [obj_number autorelease] here
obj_number = [dataset objectAtIndex:0];
```

The last line causes the leak. After that line obj_number points to the object in dataset at index 0 and no longer to the NSNumber you allocated at the beginning.

EDIT:
Like trojanfoe said, in most cases it is better to use properties as they do the memory management for you.

Comment: Actually, in the example as written, the last line doesn't cause a leak because `[[NSNumber alloc] init]` returns nil; but with a proper initializer it _would_ leak.

Comment: You're right, i changed the code so that it will leak and fits my explanation

Comment: So I guess after the line obj_number = [dataset objectAtIndex:0]; obj_number not in my ownership anymore, right? After this scope, it will be release as dataset

Comment: Short yes. Not short, you don't know it. It is possible that someone else (maybe they are in the autorelease pool) has the ownership for the object at index 0 or for dataset so they will not be released. But the only thing you need to know is if you are responsible for releasing the object (you have the ownership) or not. You should read something about memory management in Objective-C. Even with ARC it is one of the most important topics.